# How to uncompress .sqz files (PostgreSQL custom-format dumps)

Tags: compression, postgresql

I have a `*.sqz` file that I want to uncompress.
`file` says it is "PostgreSQL custom database dump - v1.12-0", but I do not want to use PostgreSQL for the job.
I suppose the file is just a large bunch of "CREATE TABLE" and "INSERT" commands run through a compression. Unfortunately, `gunzip`, `unzip`, `uncompress` all reject the file.

What compression is used and how to undo it?

Comment: “A custom-format dump is not a script for psql, but instead must be restored with pg_restore.” So that’s a no.

Comment: @DanielB Well, postgres has to be using standard `zlib` functions *somehow* behind the scenes (for "If PostgreSQL was built on a system with the zlib compression library installed, the custom dump format will compress data as it writes it to the output file"), and this might be reproducible without using postgres itself - or so was my idea. :(

Comment: Yes, it uses some compression. That doesn’t mean the compressed data can be used by other software.

Comment: IIRC it's a gzip'd tar archive with a custom header

Answer (score 2):

> I do not want to use PostgreSQL for the job

The `pg_restore` program that converts a *PostgreSQL custom database dump* into a text file (containing SQL commands and embedded data) is a client-side program that does not need a PostgreSQL server.

Its operating mode is comparable to `gunzip`, in that once installed, you would do:

```
pg_restore file.sqlz > file.sql
```

I suspect that the reason you're searching for an alternative command is you're assuming it's more complicated, for instance that the only way would be to restore into a running instance.

If you're using a Debian system for example, just do `apt-get install postgresql-client` and it will install `pg_restore` without a server.

Comment: Wow! So I can use PostgreSQl ... without using it.  :)